# $B = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:{s_j}(z) = {s_i}(z)},j\ne i \right\}$.Why does $B \ne \mathbb{C}$? ....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_j \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, ($j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m$) and

- $P(z) = A_m z^m + \cdots + A_1 z + A_0$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $z $ is a complex variable.
- $s_1 \ge s_2 \ge \cdots \ge s_n$ are singular values of $P(z)$.
- All the eigenvalues of $P(z)$ have geometric multiplicity 
  equal to $1$.
- $B = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:{s_j}(z) = {s_i}(z)},j\ne i \right\}$

Is it true that $B \ne \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I don't understand your specification of $B$. Do you mean $z$ such that all singular values are equal?

Comment: Consider $m=0$ and $A_0$ unitary.

Comment: @copper.hat - $z$ such that all singular values are equal.